# Three.js - Avoid points clipping due to camera angle

Tags: reactjs, three.js

Using Three.js and React, I am rendering a Waveform .obj with a wireframe and points on each vertex.

While rendering successfully, the points are seemingly being clipped, depending on the camera angle.

See how the bottom-most point is fully spherical, while the other points are getting clipped:

[image]

Here is my setup:

```
export const Scene: React.FC<{}> = ({}) => {
    const mountRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!mountRef.current) return;

        // Scene setup
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            // ...
        );

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        mountRef.current.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // Load OBJ model
        const loader = new OBJLoader();
        loader.load("/FaceGeometry.obj", (object) => {
            object.traverse((child) => {
                child.renderOrder = -1;
                if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
                    child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                        color: 0x555555,
                        specular: 0x111111,
                        shininess: 100,
                        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                    });

                    // Lines Material
                    const lineMaterial = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                        color: 0x888888,
                        linewidth: 1, // Note: linewidth might not be supported by all platforms
                    });
                    const wireframe = new THREE.WireframeGeometry(
                        child.geometry
                    );
                    const lineSegments = new THREE.LineSegments(
                        wireframe,
                        lineMaterial
                    );
                    scene.add(lineSegments);

                    // Points Material
                    const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
                    const sphereTexture =
                        textureLoader.load("/spherical.png");

                    const pointsMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial({
                        color: 0xff00ff,
                        map: sphereTexture,
                        size: 0.001,
                        transparent: true,
                        depthWrite: false, // Avoid depth write for better visual appearance
                        polygonOffset: true, // Enable polygon offset
                        polygonOffsetFactor: -1,
                        polygonOffsetUnits: -1,
                    });

                    // Points Geometry and Object
                    const pointsGeometry = child.geometry;

                    // Since we're using BufferGeometry, no need to convert the vertices
                    const points = new THREE.Points(
                        pointsGeometry,
                        pointsMaterial
                    );
                    points.renderOrder = 1;
                    scene.add(points);
                }
            });
            scene.add(object);
        });

        // Animation loop
        const animate = function () {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            // Any animations or updates go here
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
        };

        animate();
    }, []);

    return <div ref={mountRef}></div>;
};
```

I've tried using `depthTest: false` and setting the `renderOrder` of the points, wireframe, and mesh, but regardless the points are getting clipped.

While I could add `depthTest: false` to my `pointsMaterial`, this isn't ideal because then the points will never be occluded.

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful. Thanks!